# R - for loop error: "Unexpected '}' in '}'"

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, simulation

here is the code for a simulation I'm trying to run:

```
n_draws <- 1000

black <- rep(0, n_draws)
hispanic <- rep(0, n_draws)
asian <- rep(0, n_draws)
white <- rep(0, n_draws)


cutoff <- c(0.05,0.1,0.25,1)
draws <- runif(n_draws,0,1)

for (i in draws){
  
  if (draws[i] < cutoff[1]){
    
    black[i] <- 1
    
  } else if ((draws[i] >= cutoff[1]) & (draws[i] < cutoff[2])){
    
    hispanic[i] <- 1
    
  } else if ((draws[i] >= cutoff[2]) & (draws[i] < cutoff[3]){
    
    asian[i] <- 1
    
  } else {

white[i] <- 1

 }
}
```

Basically, I want to add a 1 to the corresponding list, conditional on where that number falls in the range (0,1). I'm not sure why this is giving an error. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing a closing bracket just after `cutoff[3]`, also used `seq_along` in my example as it's a bit nicer

```
for (i in seq_along(draws)){
  
  if (draws[i] < cutoff[1]){
    
    black[i] <- 1
    
  } else if ((draws[i] >= cutoff[1]) & (draws[i] < cutoff[2])){
    
    hispanic[i] <- 1
    
  } else if ((draws[i] >= cutoff[2]) & (draws[i] < cutoff[3])){
    
    asian[i] <- 1
    
  } else {
    
    white[i] <- 1
    
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! I had not heard of ```seq_along``` before so I'll check it out